# Django Form Submit Retain Selection Criteria

Tags: django, django-forms

New to Django / HTML.

I have a `form` on my home page. The `form` takes inputs from the user and upon clicking `submit`, the form retrieves data and displays it below the `form`.

The problem is that after `submit` is clicked, the form selection values reset to the default values.

I would like to retain the values selected by the user.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the `home.html`:

```html
      <form>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleSelect1">Example select</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1">
            <option>Apple</option>
            <option>Banana</option>
            <option>Carrot</option>
          </select>

        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" action="location.href='{% url 'app_name:view_name' %}'">SUBMIT</button>

</form>
```

And here is the `views.py`:

```html
def form1(request):

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'data':'Test'})
```

Comment: can you share your codes as well?

Comment: @arjun I have subsequently added the `html`  in question

Comment: Please also include the related sections of **views.py**. That's where you should change your code to send back data to form after submitting it.

Comment: @PedramParsian I have added the views code as requested.